# How to save an interactive plot produced by ggvis?

Tags: r, plot, ggvis

I have produced a plot using the ggvis package in R. The plot is interactive which can be changed by moving around the slider. However when I save it, it is just a picture of current status without sliders.

I have seen people posting these interactive plots on the website, so I think there should be a way to save it first.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Rstudio page](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) for ggvis:

> Note: If you’re viewing the HTML version of this document generated with knitr, the examples will have their interactive features disabled. You’ll need to run the code in R to see and use the interactive controls.

From this and the whole page I gather that sharing the interactive graphics can be done using Shiny Apps and/or R Markdown documents. To deploy either of those to people who do not have R installed you need to a) use [Shiny Apps IO](https://www.shinyapps.io/); or b) install [Shiny Server](http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/), which has a free version with very basic administration capabilities, and a paid version for confidential information in corporate environment (which I'm only mentioning in case you are not allowed to share your data).

Either way, read through the [Shiny Tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/), the
[R Markdown Tutorial](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/), and the [combination](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

Comment: Thanks Martin I'd take a look at that :)